# How to debug virtual table plugin in dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I can't find a way to debug the plugin code of a virtual table. As step is generated by external implementation. I would like to find a way to debug the code in real time. Would anyone have a solution?

[image: Stpe Plugin Registration]

I'm using throw error to try to capture data and validate, which is a lot of work.

Comment: It is not possible to do real time debugging on dynamics 365 plugins. As far as I know writing unit tests is the proper way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach similar to the one I described in my post - https://butenko.pro/2022/01/03/debugging-custom-api-plugins-using-plugin-registration-tool/